# Sharepoint calculated column date calculation

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint, datediff

I have a list in SharePoint Office 365 with a number of columns to register and track claims.

One of the columns is a calculated one - to catch the duration of claims processing.

I would like to calculate it as a difference between dates and shown in days.

To do it I want to use 3 pieces of information:

- Column `[RegistrationDate]`

  - Date of new registered claim.
- Column `[EndDate]`

  - Finalization of the claim.
- [Today]

  - Sytem date for `now`.

The logic to be done by the formula should be:

- IF `[EndDate]` is empty THEN:

  - `[Today]-[RegistrationDate]`
- OTHERWISE

  - `[EndDate]-[RegistrationDate]`

**Question:** What formula will achieve my desired output?

Comment: The question and possible pros and cons of workarounds have already been treated in other places like [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column)

Answer (score 0):

Calculated columns cannot use the [Today] dynamic variable. (Validation formulas can.) Calculated Columns are only updated when they are edited, not each time they are viewed.

***If you could use [Today]***, it would look like this:

=IF( ISBLANK( [EndDate] ), [Today]-[RegistrationDate], [EndDate]-[RegistrationDate] )

But... you cannot use [Today] in a calculated column...